# PostgreSQL Inner Join Where Get IDs of 3 Products

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, odoo-9

I have these 5 tables which is `sale_order` directly connected to `sale_order_line` that has the products of the order of course which is connected to `product_product` that is connected to `product_template` where a table called `mrp_bom` can connect to product template and a table connected to it which is `bom_line`. I am trying to Output the products that contain the word `836g`

Here is what I have so far:

```
Select      so.name,
    pt.name,
    sol.name
From    sale_order so

Inner   Join sale_order_line sol
On  so.id = sol.order_id
Inner   Join product_template pt
On  sol.product_id = pt.id
Inner   Join mrp_bom bom
On  pt.id = bom.product_tmpl_id
Inner   Join mrp_bom_line boml
On  bom.id = boml.bom_id

Where   boml.product_id = (Select id From product_template Where name Like '%836g%'

Order   By so.name
```

This code outputs an error because I have 3 items with `836g`. I tried changing the `=` in the condition into `IN` so it will grab all the `id`s it will return. But still it's giving me an error. This is the best I have so far, I have tried so many times, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use this: `WHERE pt.id LIKE '%836g%'` ?  Can you show us sample input and output?

Comment: its id is not a string. 836g is just a portion of one of my products..

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?  They are very different databases.

Comment: I am using Postgresql.. Sorry for the tag!

Comment: Your current query should run without error, minus the missing right parenthesis on the subquery.  What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that something along these lines is what you actually want:

```
SELECT so.name,
       pt.name,
       sol.name
FROM sale_order so
INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol
    ON so.id = sol.order_id
INNER JOIN product_template pt
    ON sol.product_id = pt.id
INNER JOIN mrp_bom bom
    ON pt.id = bom.product_tmpl_id
INNER JOIN mrp_bom_line boml
    ON bom.id = boml.bom_id
WHERE pt.name LIKE '%836g%'     -- just add a WHERE condition directly in your query
ORDER BY so.name
```

Comment: I already tried this one earlier before i had my posted question but thanks for the effort!

Comment: What error do you get?  Can you show us sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

OMG! I just had the answer. I don't think this will help anyone but i'll post the answer i have

```
SELECT so.name,
   pt.name PT,
   sol.name SOL,
   (Select pp1.name_template From product_product pp1 Where boml.product_id = pp1.id) BOML,
   boml.product_id
```

FROM sale_order so
INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol
    ON so.id = sol.order_id
INNER JOIN product_template pt
    ON sol.product_id = pt.id
INNER JOIN mrp_bom bom
    ON pt.id = bom.product_tmpl_id
INNER JOIN mrp_bom_line boml
    ON bom.id = boml.bom_id
WHERE (Select pp1.name_template From product_product pp1 Where boml.product_id = pp1.id) LIKE '%836g%'
ORDER BY so.name

Thank you all for the effort of helping me! Great community we got here! :D